# Django Rest Framework: make a serializer field not required in post data when perform create re

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following setup:

**Models.py**

```
class QuoteModel(models.Model):
    """
        this model stores initial information for the Quote
    """
    quote_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                    unique=True,
                                    help_text="Please use the quote number from pms",)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                   help_text="Enter description that you might find helpful")
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
# Serializers define the API representation.
class QuoteModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = ('id', 'quote_number', 'description', 'creator', 'date_created')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created',)
```

**View.py**

```
class QuoteListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Quote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuoteModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)
```

In the snippet, I am setting up the `creator` field of `QuoteModel` in the view's `perform_create` method. Since `QuoteListCreateView` is an authenticated only view, therefore, I don't want to pass the `creator` during the quote create request (post to `/quotes`). `creator` is a part of the serializer class, the post request returns the following if I don't pass the creator.
"creator": [
    "This field is required."
  ]"

Therefore, my question is-
   Is there anyway to make the `creator` parameter optional on post request? I can not add `null=true` on `creator` field in model.py  because it is required from models perspective.

Thanks in advance.

**Fix**

overriding the `creator` attribute in the model serializer and set required to False resolved the issue.

```
class QuoteModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False, queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = ('id', 'quote_number', 'description', 'creator', 'date_created')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created',)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem. Specifically:

> I don't want to pass the creator during the quote create request.

It sounds like you want the creator field to be read-only, yet be populated on create. If this is the case, I suggest you use the following:

```
class QuoteModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = ('id', 'quote_number', 'description', 'creator', 'date_created')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created',)
```